# I want to have expansion options for each row like a hierarchy

Tags: excel

I am having different levels of nodes in each row [image]like 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.1.1 and so on. how i need is if i click on 1.1, it should expand to show 1.1.1 and furthur on clicking 1.1.1 it should expand to show 1.1.1.1

Comment: How is this related to Unix & Linux?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a Unix/Linux question